# Saitek X45 hat not working

Tags: controllers

I have an old Saitek X45. For years it has worked fine but now the Hat button 2 has stopped working. Does anyone know how it may be fixed.

Comment: Well, since I have worked in support, the saying goes "everything that broke was working yesterday".  Probably best to contact Saitek for troubleshooting guidelines.